# Conversion error with Entity and Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I got the error

```
cannot implicity convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<EntityNetimoveis.San_Imovel>' to 'EntityNetimoveis.San_Imovel' An Explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast ?)
```

This occurs when I try the following code

```
EntityNetimoveis.San2011Entities db = new EntityNetimoveis.San2011Entities();
EntityNetimoveis.San_Imovel im = db.San_Imovel.Where(a => a.Credenciada_Id == 10);
```

What type of conversion I have to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
EntityNetimoveis.San_Imovel im = db.San_Imovel.Where(a => a.Credenciada_Id == 10);
```

The type of im is an `IQueryable<EntityNetimoveis.San_Imovel>` because you are running a where query and there might be more than one result. If you want the first result matching your query you should use .FirstOrDefault(). Try changing you code as:

```
EntityNetimoveis.San_Imovel im = db.San_Imovel.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Credenciada_Id == 10);
```

If you want to return more than one entity and process them, lets say using a foreach loop, then you need to change the type of the return value to `IEnumerable<Netimoveis.San_Imovel>`. See the following example:

```
IEnumerable<EntityNetimoveis.San_Imovel> ims = db.San_Imovel.Where(a => a.Credenciada_Id == 10);
```

The you can use the following:

```
foreach(var im in ims) {
    // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: But I need more than one result, can be millions of registers that has `a.Credenciada_Id == 10`. I need to save this in `Entity.San_Imovel` and then I need to do a `ForEach`. How can I perform this ?

Answer (score 2):

If the lambda can return more than one record:

```
var imList = db.San_Imovel.Where(a => a.Credenciada_Id == 10).ToList();
```

Comment: I have to return all register in my database that has the column `Credenciada_Id` equals 10. Can be millions of registers, so I need to put in San_Imovel all these registers, and then I'll do a `Foreach`

Comment: [Is](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/afb292ca-3a61-4a60-8e18-830b92489016/) `SingleOrDefault` supported in Linq-To-Enitities?

Comment: Exists, but I need to return more then one result.

Comment: @Lucas_Santos The expression Massimiliano is using will return a List<SanIMovel>.  Theoretically, you could leave off the .ToList part and you'd have a IQueryable<SanIMovel>, which implements IEnumerable<SanIMovel>.  Both methods will give you more than one result if more than one result exist.